# Scaling given view and screen width behaviour to be same for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-view

I have a requirement to make a particular button view.

As per the requirements, the max width of button text is specified as 48px, when the screen width size is given as 360px. But since the resolution can be different for different devices, to satisfy the requirement, I am using

```
screenWidth = context.resources.displayMetrics.WidthPixels
```

and then using the ratio **(screenWidth*48)/360** to set the maxWidth of the button text like so:

```
button.title.maxWidth = (screenWidth * 48) / 360
```

My question is that how can I better satisfy the requirements, without using these ratios? Also is there a way to use dps instead of pixels in this situation?

Comment: Read it- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 0):

Use Autosizing TextViews.
Read the developers [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) for more information.

Comment: I don't want the font size to change (unless user explicitly chooses font size in system settings). I just want the view itself to scale.

Comment: Then use- https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout